# ¿Es posible utilizar esta expresión para enfatizar o reafirmar algo?

Tags: uso-de-palabras

¿Es posible utilizar la expresión "como lo deben ellas ser" como en el siguiente poema para enfatizar o reafirmar algo que se está diciendo? ¿Es esto gramaticalmente correcto?

Mis canciones de amor son alegres y festivas, como lo deben ellas ser

Besos que no conozco, los intento conocer

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

“Como lo deben ellas ser” es gramaticalmente correcto, pero muy poco natural. En poemas y canciones muchas veces aparecen expresiones como estas, donde la elección o el orden de las palabras no son los habituales. En un texto común o en el idioma hablado, diríamos “como deben ser” o “como deben serlo”.

Comment: Muchas gracias por su ayuda. También tenemos en portugués muchas expresiones que suenan bien cuando se usan poéticamente pero que rara vez se usarían coloquialmente. Gracias también por las alternativas presentadas.

Comment: agregando a los ejemplos de @pablodf76 "como lo deben ser" también es común.
No estoy seguro respecto al uso de "ellas", quizá por ser en sentido poético es válido? Lo digo porque normalmente usaría un pronombre demostrativo